# How can I copy different file types in Python while keeping their directory structure

Tags: python, operating-system, shutil, copytree

I'm new to using Spyder 2.3.0 and Python 3.4.1

I have a directory structure with sub directories.

Unlike other examples on the web I want to select multiple file types and copy the directory structure across. I have tried below and it works but it takes only one file type at a time and “`copytree`’s” across (it’s going to be very slow).

Is there a way or different way to streamline this to make it faster?

What I was thinking I wanted to do was:

Make a comprehensive list of file types and locations (walking through directory structure)

For example ending with

```
fileExt = [".txt", ".doc", ".docx", ".xls",".xlsx", ".ppt", ".pptx", ".m", ".xmcd", ".pdf " ]
```

Then with that list simply “`shutil.copytree`”

Any advice greatly appreciated.

```
  srcDir  = 'c:/a/src/dir/'
  dirName = 'c:/a/dest/dir/'


import os
import shutil

##################################################################################

dstDir = os.path.abspath(dirName)

def ignore_list(path, files):

    filesToIgnore = []

    for fileName in files:

        fullFileName = os.path.join(os.path.normpath(path), fileName)

        if not os.path.isdir(fullFileName) and not fileName.endswith('.txt') :

            filesToIgnore.append(fileName)

    return filesToIgnore

# start of script

shutil.copytree(srcDir, dstDir, ignore=ignore_list)
####################################################################################################################################################################

dstDir = os.path.abspath(dirName)

def ignore_list(path, files):

    filesToIgnore = []

    for fileName in files:

        fullFileName = os.path.join(os.path.normpath(path), fileName)

        if not os.path.isdir(fullFileName) and not fileName.endswith('.docx') :


            filesToIgnore.append(fileName)

    return filesToIgnore

# start of script

shutil.copytree(srcDir, dstDir, ignore=ignore_list)

####################################################
```

Copy and paste changing “endswith('.docx') :”

Comment: perhaps fnmatch helps. Please look here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/fnmatch.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can perform your "ignore_list" method a little bit more

```
valid_formats = ["txt", "doc", "docx", "xls","xlsx", "ppt", "pptx", "m", "xmcd", "pdf "]

import timeit
import os.path as op

def ignore_list(path, files):
    dag_path = [op.join(op.normpath(path), f) for f in files]
    return [ff for ff in dag_path if not op.isdir(ff) and ff.split(".")[-1] not in valid_formats]

start = timeit.default_timer()
ignore = ignore_list(path, files)
print ("Time: {0}".format(str(timeit.default_timer()-start)))
```

Comment: I’m very new to programming (35 year old mechanical engineer), like in my working example I have:   
srcDir  = 'c:/a/src/dir/'
dirName = 'c:/a/dest/dir/'

could you please give me a full example that I could use.
I like the ”valid_formats” idea

Thanks

Comment: the "ignore = ignore_list(path, files)" keeps throwing up an error in Spyder

Comment: replace in ignore_list...dag_path = [(op.join(op.normpath(path), f)) for f in files], () is missing, sry

Answer (score 0):

This works, I know its not pretty but it works

```
srcDir  = 'c:/a/src/dir/
dstDir = 'c:/a/dest/dir/'


A01= '.doc'
A02= '.docx'
A03= '.xls'
A04= '.xlsx'
A05= '.ppt'
A06= '.pptx'
A07= '.m'
A08= '.xmcd'
A09= '.inp'
A10= '.pdf'
A11= '.DOC'
A12= '.DOCX'
A13= '.XLS'
A14= '.XLSX'
A15= '.PPT'
A16= '.PPTX'
A17= '.M'
A18= '.XMCD'
A19= '.INP'
A20= '.PDF'



import os
import shutil

#########################################################################################################


def ignore_list(path, files):

    filesToIgnore = []

    for fileName in files:

        fullFileName = os.path.join(os.path.normpath(path), fileName)

        if not os.path.isdir(fullFileName) and not fileName.endswith(A01) and not fileName.endswith(A02) and not fileName.endswith(A03) and not fileName.endswith(A04) and not fileName.endswith(A05) and not fileName.endswith(A06) and not fileName.endswith(A07) and not fileName.endswith(A08) and not fileName.endswith(A09) and not fileName.endswith(A10) and not fileName.endswith(A11) and not fileName.endswith(A12) and not fileName.endswith(A13) and not fileName.endswith(A14) and not fileName.endswith(A15) and not fileName.endswith(A16) and not fileName.endswith(A17) and not fileName.endswith(A18) and not fileName.endswith(A19) and not fileName.endswith(A20) :


            filesToIgnore.append(fileName)

    return filesToIgnore




shutil.copytree(srcDir, dstDir, ignore=ignore_list)

#########################################################################################################
```